# Working with Hive Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, hive

File1: Id file

```
id   interests_code
1         1,2
2         2,3
3         1,4
```

File2: Interests file

```
1 Football
2 Cricket
3 Baseball
4 Hockey
```

Here in File1, the column interests_code is an array of elements (array), I would like to create an output file as,

```
id    interests
1     Football,Cricket
2     Cricket,Baseball
3     Football,Hockey
```

Can a Join be done on a Column of array to another table?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better normalize your database design.

But if you want get result from the current table structure, try:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.interest) AS interests
FROM id_file t1
LEFT JOIN interests_file t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, t1.interests_code)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: But I have tried submitting the query in HIVE but it looks like the function GROUP_CONCAT is unavailable in HIVE. But I have come across COLLECT_SET. I'm trying to achieve the same using this. Any help!